# How to fail on unknown XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In my Spring Boot 2.1 application I want to provide an XML-HTTP-API.

Building on an existing XSD-Schema, I generated java classes (using jaxb). The generated code roughly looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CustomerRequestType", propOrder = {
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
})
public class CustomerRequestType {

    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    protected List<FirstNameType> firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    protected List<LastNameType> lastName;

    // ...getter methods...
}
```

My spring boot RestControllers look like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("customer.xml")
public class CustomerController {

    @PostMapping
    public CustomerResponseType postCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerRequestType anfrage) {
      // ...business code...
    }
}
```

How can I let spring boot with jackson fail, when deserializing requests with unknown tags or properties like this?

```
<Customer>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <lastName>Schmitt</lastName>

    <unknownTag unknownProperty="1234"/>

</Customer>
```

I tried to set jackson to strict mode by setting this property (although the docs told me, that it is set to `true` by default anyways), but the webservice still returns status 200:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which converter is used by `Spring-Boot` to deserialise `XML` payload. In your case it could be `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`. To use `Jackson` properties you need to use `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` which could check unknown properties and throw `UnrecognizedPropertyException` exception. To customise `Jackson`'s mapper configuration we can use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean.

Take a look on below example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class JacksonMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer;

    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder xmlBuilder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml();
        customizer.customize(xmlBuilder);

        return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(xmlBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Jackson` for deserialising classes annotated with `JAXB` annotation consider to use [JaxbAnnotationModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/jaxb).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Jackson is primarily used for JSON data. It also supports XML and some JAXB-annotations. But it does not support XML schema validation.

It seems, you are actually looking for schema validation. Then you should use JAXB as XML marshaller.

Also see:
[Spring JAXB - Unmarshalling an XML document with schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267288/spring-jaxb-unmarshalling-an-xml-document-with-schema-validation/9302562)